# Slim select doesn't work when embedded in a modal

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown, slimselect

When I use a slim select in bootstrap modal, I can't type anything into it.  Outside the modal slim select works fine.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modal-report"  role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">New report</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Client name</label>
                  <select id="selectElement">
                    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
                    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
                    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Reporting period</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div>
                  <label class="form-label">Additional information</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link link-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
              Cancel
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
              <!-- Download SVG icon from http://tabler-icons.io/i/plus -->
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M12 5l0 14" /><path d="M5 12l14 0" /></svg>
              Create new report
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        new SlimSelect({
            select: '#selectElement'
        });
    });
</script>
```

In modal Search box is not working or clickable. But outside modal its working fine. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: just added data-bs-focus="false" to modal element. And issue is fixed.